# E_Error cannot redeclare function - function previously declared can not be redeclared

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I got a mail from my webmaster that there was an fatal error in the theme we are currently using in Wordpress.

The function was declared here first:

```
function porto_ct_post_media_types() {

return array(
    'images' => __( 'Slideshow', 'porto' ),
    'grid'   => __( 'Grid Images', 'porto' ),
    'video'  => __( 'Video & Audio or Content', 'porto' ),
    'none'   => __( 'None', 'porto' ),
);}
```

The second time the function was redeclared it looks like this

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'porto_ct_post_media_types' ) ) :
function porto_ct_post_media_types() {

    return array(
        'images' => __( 'Slideshow', 'porto' ),
        'grid'   => __( 'Grid Images', 'porto' ),
        'video'  => __( 'Video & Audio or Content', 'porto' ),
        'none'   => __( 'None', 'porto' ),
    );
}endif;
```

I found it strange as this is done  a few times before this, with other functions redeclared in the same way, it gave an error here.

I have not tried fixing it as I was not sure why the error returned on this particular place in the theme files. Help will be very appreciated.

Comment: if ( ! function_exists( 'porto_ct_post_media_types' ) Is usualy used for parent theme allowing override in child theme. So the parent should be with condition and child without condition.

Comment: I get what you mean, but both functions were in the parent theme folders.

Comment: There is no logic to have 2 times same function right ? If you didnt do changes to any theme file contact your developer . I would suggest to remove the one with no condition, makes more sence.